# How to customize picture view in edit form using VichUploader bundle

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms, vichuploaderbundle

I have problem when rendering image with symfony form using VichUploader bundle.

When I ulpoad picture with big resolution, picture is over entire form.

How to change height and weiht of rendering image in symfony forms?

Answer (score -1):

The UploadableField annotation has a `dimensions` option.

Comment: Can you give me example I didnt see in documentation

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Kriscius. Better than one sentence answers are minimal working code samples.